# SwiftUI and enum in picker

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I am working in a playground trying to learn SwiftUI.  I am creating a view that includes a label, a text field, text to show the value of the picker and the picker.

What I have so far is this

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport
import SwiftUI

enum Units: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable
{
    case Inches = "in"
    case Millimeters = "mm"
    case Centimeters = "cm"
    
    var id: String { self.rawValue }
}

struct VariableView: View
{
    let name: String
    let labelValue: String
    @State private var inputValue = ""
    @State private var inputUnits = Units.Inches
    
    init(name: String, label: String)
    {
        self.name = name
        labelValue = label
    }
    
    var body: some View
    {
        VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0)
        {
            Text(self.labelValue)
                .font(.subheadline)
                .frame(width: .infinity, alignment: .leading)
                .padding(.horizontal, 4)
            HStack
            {
                TextField("Value", text: $inputValue)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 4)
                    .keyboardType(.numbersAndPunctuation)
                Text(inputUnits.id)
                Picker("...", selection: $inputUnits)
                {
                    /*
                    Text("Inches").tag(Units.Inches)
                    Text("Millimeters").tag(Units.Millimeters)
                    Text("Centimeters").tag(Units.Centimeters)
                     */
                    ForEach(Units.allCases)
                    {
                        unit in Text(unit.rawValue.capitalized)
                    }
                }
                .padding(10)
                .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
            }
            Divider()
             .frame(height: 1)
             .padding(.horizontal, 30)
             .background(Color.black)
        }
    }
}

// Make a SwiftUI view
struct ContentView: View
{
    var body: some View
    {
        VariableView(name: "value1", label: "Value 1")
        VariableView(name: "value1", label: "Value 2")
        VariableView(name: "value1", label: "Value 3")
        VariableView(name: "value1", label: "Value 4")
        VariableView(name: "value1", label: "Value 5")
    }
}

// Make a UIHostingController
let viewController = UIHostingController(rootView: ContentView())

// Assign it to the playground's liveView
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = viewController
```

When I click on the "...", it crashes.  Turns to black and stops running.  No error, just stops.

If I use the three text lines (currently commented out) instead of the ForEach, it works - but eventually I'll need to be able to dynamically set the allowed units for each input, so I need the ForEach working.

Comment: This looks like a Playground limitation (probably the picker menu style). This code runs fine in the simulator.

Comment: Try simulator or real device - works fine here. I assume it is a bug of Playground.

Comment: Thanks guys. I thought I was going crazy.  It is possible to run a playground in the simulator?

Comment: @jbmillard was the answer useful?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of inputTypes is Units and the tag on the hardcoded Texts match that type. In the ForEach the tag is Units.rawValue and that type is String. See if this works in the Playground:

```
struct PickFromEnumView: View {
    @State private var inputUnits = Units.none
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Picker(inputUnits.rawValue, selection: $inputUnits) {
                ForEach(Units.allCases) { unit in
                    unit.label.tag(unit)
                }
            }
            .padding(10)
            .pickerStyle(MenuPickerStyle())
            Spacer()
        }
    }
    
    enum Units: String, CaseIterable, Identifiable
    {
        case none = "…"
        case inches = "in"
        case millimeters = "mm"
        case centimeters = "cm"
        
        var id: String { self.rawValue }
        
        var label : some View {
            switch(self) {
            case .none: return Label("…", systemImage: "circle")
            case .inches: return Label("inch", systemImage: "1.circle")
            case .millimeters: return Label("millimeter", systemImage: "2.circle")
            case .centimeters: return Label("centimeter", systemImage: "3.circle")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for that, but it crashes too.  I'm chalking this one up to a playground bug.  I have it working in the simulator.